How do pass a DataFrame containing a single row rather than two dimensional using RandomForestClassifier
# In\[2\]:

import yfinance as yfan

# In\[3\]:

sp500 = yfan.Ticker("^GSPC")

# In\[4\]:

sp500 = sp500.history(period="max")

# In\[5\]:

sp500

# In\[6\]:

sp500.index

# In\[7\]:

sp500.plot.line(y="Close", use_index=True)

# In\[8\]:

del sp500\["Dividends"\]
del sp500\["Stock Splits"\]

# In\[9\]:

sp500\["Tomorrow"\]=sp500\["Close"\].shift(-1)

# In\[10\]:

sp500

# In\[11\]:

sp500\["Target"\] = (sp500\["Tomorrow"\]\>sp500\["Close"\]).astype(int)

# In\[12\]:

sp500

# In\[13\]:

sp500 = sp500.loc\["1990-01-01":\].copy()

# In\[14\]:

sp500

# In\[31\]:

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, min_samples_split=100, random_state=1)

train = sp500.iloc\[:-100\]
test = sp500.iloc\[-100\]

predictors = \["Close", "Volume", "Open", "High", "Low"\]
model.fit(train\[predictors\], train\["Target"\])

# In\[36\]:

from sklearn.metrics import precision_score

preds = model.predict(test\[predictors\])`

Above is the code I have so far in python. The issue is that whenever I run the last line of the code (everything else works as I want it to), I get a long error which i am unsure how to fix or even approach.
The following is the ValueError:
ValueError: Expected a 2-dimensional container but got <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> instead. Pass a DataFrame containing a single row (i.e. single sample) or a single column (i.e. single feature) instead

I trie to fidget with the syntax of the code, but that did not work and made the errors even worse. I am not really sure what to do at this point.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
